# List of items implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged

What is the best way to implement collection of items, where:

1. each item could be of different type
2. each item will raise PropertyChanged event on its change (parent class implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

Update:

I'm thinking on something like this:
Collection:

```
["Name", string:"John Doe"]
["Age", int:"32"]
["Profiles", List<Profiles>:"list of profiles"]
```

I will be able to add new item like this:

```
Collection.Add("NewItem", value);
```

And then change it:

```
Collection["NewItem"] = newValue;
```

Which will trigger event:

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("NewItem");
```

So, as a result, I will be able to subscribe to every-single item from that collection and have different event handlers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need from your description is what I (and others) would call an `ObservableDictionary`, which Google will give you several suggestions for implementing.  There's no such class built in to .NET, but there are tuturials and third-party implementations a-plenty.

The reasons I say this:

- the correct interface for notifying that the content of a collection has changed is [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), not `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  When you add an item or call `Collection["NewItem"] = newValue`, the event you should fire is `CollectionChanged`, because it's not a *property* of the list that has changed - it's the *content*
- you're clearly intending for your list to have key/value pairs, which means you can't easily use the existing `ObservableCollection` class.

Separately, you say "I will be able to subscribe to every-single item from that collection," which suggests that you *may* want to limit the "values" in your dictionary to be `INotifyPropertyChanged` but, I would suggest, you should create your `ObservableDictionary` as a generic class, and then you can choose to have the values in the dictionary be any type you need.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be a list, use

```
ObservableCollection<INotifyPropertyChanged>
```

Comment: That won't work according to the requirements - the question is using a keyed collection, like a `Dictionary`.

Comment: oh right, OP updated the question after I submitted my answer.